# Opening of the JInternalFrame in the same mode as of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jinternalframe

I have a JFrame which further have 4 JInternalFrames. From JFrame i have the links to open any of these JInternalFrames.I just want to ask is there any way by which if i open the JFrame in maximized mode then all other internal frames will also get open in the maximized mode. Smilarly if JFrame is not in maximized mode then others should also not open in maximized mode.

thanks for giving your time.

I used setMaximum() But now i am facing one more issue. If i open internal frames consecutively then they
all will get opened in maximized mode, which is good since my JFrame is also in maximizd mode. But as soon as i close the latest opened frame they all will be in default size not in maximized mode.

The problem here is that after this when i do a single click on any internal frame they
will become maximized. If i click restore button then again if i click other internal framess they all will 
open in default size not in maximized mode i.e. if i click maximized button then do click on other internl
frames they open in maximized mode and if i click restore button they will open in the default size.

// For the first time when internal frame is getting open

```
if (isNewEditor)

{

((GenericEditor)editorFrame).setQFTestName(((JInternalFrame)editorObject).getTitle());
                editorFrame.setSize(defaultWidth, defaultHeight);
                editorFrame.setVisible(true);
                addFrameToDesktop(editorFrame); // adding to JDesktopPane
              editorFrame.setMaximum(true);
              editorFrame.setSelected(true);
              editorFrame.moveToFront();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JInternalFrame has a `setMaximum(...)` method. A JFrame has a `getExtendedState()` method.

When you create and display the internal frame you can query the state of the frame and set the internal frame to maximum as required.

Comment: After using setMaximum() the jframes are opening but when i close the latest frame they all will display in default size and if i click anywhere in any of these windows they will again become maximized. Details are updated in question. Thanks